# Reading a json webpage using python

Tags: python, json, pandas, analytics, json-normalize

I am trying to read a json webpage and insert it into a dataframe.

```py
import urllib3
import json
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/owid-covid-data.json'
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
r = http.request('GET', url, headers={'Accept': 'application/json'})

data = json.loads(r.data.decode('utf-8'))
data_copy = data

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_copy, orient='index')
df.transpose()
```

[image: The link shows an image of my python code and the output I am getting]

I need to use the same code I previewed but the output has to be in the following format:

[image: desired output]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution for this specific data:

```
req = requests.get("https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/owid-covid-data.json")
d = json.loads(req.content)
records = [{**{"iso_code": key}, **item} for key, val in d.items() for item in val]

pd.DataFrame.from_records(records)
```

The result is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- This implementation results in the desired output form.
- Only `pandas` is required.
- Directly read the `url` with [`pandas.read_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html)
- Use [`pandas.DataFrame.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to stack all the columns of dictionaries into one column.
- As of pandas v1.0.0, [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) is in the top level name space.

  - Otherwise, use `from pandas.io.json import json_normalize` and replace `pd.json_normalize(df2[0])` with `json_normalize(df2[0])`

```py
import pandas as pd

# read data with pandas
df = pd.read_json('https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/owid-covid-data.json', orient='index')

# stack all the dictionary columns
df2 = df.stack().reset_index()

# use json_normalize to expand dicts, drop and rename columns
df2 = df2.join(pd.json_normalize(df2[0])).drop(columns=['level_1', 0]).rename(columns={'level_0': 'iso_code'})

iso_code location        date  total_cases  new_cases  total_deaths  new_deaths  total_cases_per_million  new_cases_per_million  total_deaths_per_million  new_deaths_per_million  stringency_index  population  population_density  median_age  aged_65_older  aged_70_older  gdp_per_capita  diabetes_prevalence  cvd_death_rate  handwashing_facilities  hospital_beds_per_100k  extreme_poverty  female_smokers  male_smokers  total_tests  total_tests_per_thousand tests_units  new_tests  new_tests_per_thousand  new_tests_smoothed  new_tests_smoothed_per_thousand
     ABW    Aruba  2020-03-13            2          2             0           0                   18.733                 18.733                       0.0                     0.0              0.00    106766.0               584.8        41.2         13.085          7.452       35973.781                11.62             NaN                     NaN                     NaN              NaN             NaN           NaN          NaN                       NaN         NaN        NaN                     NaN                 NaN                              NaN
     ABW    Aruba  2020-03-20            4          2             0           0                   37.465                 18.733                       0.0                     0.0             30.56    106766.0               584.8        41.2         13.085          7.452       35973.781                11.62             NaN                     NaN                     NaN              NaN             NaN           NaN          NaN                       NaN         NaN        NaN                     NaN                 NaN                              NaN
     ABW    Aruba  2020-03-24           12          8             0           0                  112.395                 74.930                       0.0                     0.0             41.67    106766.0               584.8        41.2         13.085          7.452       35973.781                11.62             NaN                     NaN                     NaN              NaN             NaN           NaN          NaN                       NaN         NaN        NaN                     NaN                 NaN                              NaN
     ABW    Aruba  2020-03-25           17          5             0           0                  159.227                 46.831                       0.0                     0.0             41.67    106766.0               584.8        41.2         13.085          7.452       35973.781                11.62             NaN                     NaN                     NaN              NaN             NaN           NaN          NaN                       NaN         NaN        NaN                     NaN                 NaN                              NaN
     ABW    Aruba  2020-03-26           19          2             0           0                  177.959                 18.733                       0.0                     0.0             41.67    106766.0               584.8        41.2         13.085          7.452       35973.781                11.62             NaN                     NaN                     NaN              NaN             NaN           NaN          NaN                       NaN         NaN        NaN                     NaN                 NaN                              NaN
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dictionary()
```

use

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records()
```

This method converts structured or record ndarray to DataFrame. If i had some code i would have tried to code the solution.